# Speed up the rotation of a D3 orthographic globe

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geo

Within my app, I need to periodically speed up or slow down the rotation of a D3 orthographic globe. Now, I do this by calling the following function:

```
rotateMap(velocity = 0.01) {
    const land = topojson.feature(window.world, world.objects.land);

    window.rotationTimer = d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
        projection.rotate([velocity * elapsed, 0]);
        window.topoJsonPath.attr("d", geoPath(land));
    });
}

rotateMap(0.5)
```

The function accepts a velocity to change the speed of the map. When I pass through a quicker velocity, the globe speeds up, but there is no smooth acceleration, and the transition is jerky.

Is there a way within D3 to smoothly adjust the velocity of my globe's rotation? I've dug into the D3 Geo docs, but haven't found anything applicable.

Comment: choose a time to change the speed to the new value, if `elapsed` is less then this interval use https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate to interpolate the number and you can use https://github.com/d3/d3-ease to change the speed change